# CheckedListBox, Change state without selecting the item

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing a problem, where i'm using CheckedListBox and clicking on a checkbox results in an automatic selection of an item. This behaviour is wrong for me.

There are dosen of solutions of problems which may seem similar, but they are all suggesting to use `CheckOnClick` which is not solving the problem at all.

The user will be present with a list of 50~ items, and clicking on an item (thus selecting it) results in an operation `A`, but when user changes the state of a checkbox, operation `B` should be performed. SO, currently, due to the way it works, `A` and `B` are always performed which is not good and it stresses the application.

Is there a way to handle mouse click in such a way that it only selects the item when user clicks the `Name` portion, and only changes check box state when user clicks the checkbox?

Comment: You can use a `ListView` instead.

Comment: Indeed. They do it right out of the box. And they are much more extensible..